# Facebook oauth in iOS app not redirecting to server. Returns junk html

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, redirect, oauth

When calling the below facebook oauth url from the iOS app, a bunch of html is returned, and the redirect to our web server is never initiated.

**URL:**
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[OUR_ID]&redirect_uri=[OUR_URL]&state=%28null%29%2C200%2Cfalse%2C%3CUIDevice%3A+0x983dfb0%3E%2C5.1%2CFB_DEV

**Expected Behavior:** 
The redirect_uri portion of the url should redirect to our web server and authenticate the user.

**Actual Behavior:** 
Our web server never gets called. Instead junk html is returned in the request response data.

This worked for months, and just started failing on 2/20/2013. We are at a loss as to what could be causing this.

Our application is out of commission until this is resolved, so any assistance is appreciated!